# Proper way to add <h1> tag to a wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I am customizing a Wordpress plugin and can't seem to figure out how to properly add the `<h1>` tag to the section where it brings in my post title. I keep getting errors every way I try it.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3'); ?>

<?php 

    $category = get_option('wpns_category');

    $n_slices = get_option('wpns_slices');

?>

<?php if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            echo '<a href="';
            the_permalink();
            echo '">';
the_post_thumbnail('slider-image', array( 'alt' =>
get_the_title(), 'title' => get_the_title() . "<br /><br /> <span>" . get_the_excerpt() .
"</span>"));
            echo '</a>'; } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2>Not Found</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried for example `<h1>get_the_title(), 'title' =></h1>` but obviously that's not correct. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  'title' => "<h1>" . get_the_title() . "</h1><br/>.....
```

Comment: @Orbit: That worked! Just so I understand, adding the `.` after the addition of the `<h1>` in quotes means "and"? As in "this will be a heading, and then get the title and then create a line break?"

Comment: @themerlinproject: I'm not sure why it is being voted down, it worked.

Comment: Don't put a <br> after the <h1> tag though.

Comment: That was in the original code, just included it to show where to put the extra header tag, thanks for the up though.